# How can I alternate custom cell styles in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView` with two custom cell classes. I’d like to alternate between the two cell styles, but nothing I try seems to work. I’m coding in a Playground (it’s a requirement, as this project is for a contest), and every time I run my code I get the error “there was a problem running this page, check your code and try again, if you’re stuck delete everything on this page and start over”. Anyone know what I’m doing wrong? Maybe you have a suggestion on another technique?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let textMessages = [
        "Here's my very first message",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Messages"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_1")
        tableView.register(ChatMessageCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_2")
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textMessages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
        let secondcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell2

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 1{
            cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }else{
            secondcell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            return secondcell
        }
    }
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
        //        cell.textLabel?.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
        //        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
}

class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let bubbleBackgroundView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bubbleBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)

        addSubview(messageLabel)
        //        messageLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        messageLabel.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // lets set up some constraints for our label
        let constraints = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
                           messageLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

                           bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        //        messageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class ChatMessageCell2: UITableViewCell {

    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let bubbleBackgroundView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bubbleBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)

        addSubview(messageLabel)

        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        let constraints = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
                           messageLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

                           bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        //        messageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: I could run your code in the playground.. did you try your code in a new playground?

Comment: in 'cellForRowAt' you create both cells, but only return one, and you have the same code to update the message - you could tidy the code up.  You also repeat a lot of identical code in the custom cell creation - why not put that in a common function, then you only have to change it once?

Comment: I could run your code and it is working only when returning a 'cell_1' in cellForRowAtIndex method. The "secondcell" code was commented and it runs perfectly but when same code uncommented then it started showing error.